# javascript working with mouse events

Tags: javascript

How can I get the image to be dragged around just if the mouse is clicked, not just follow the mouse around as it is doing right now.

```
<head>
<style>
    #flying {
        position: absolute; 
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateFlyingObj (event) {
        var mouseX = Math.round (event.clientX);
        var mouseY = Math.round (event.clientY);

        var flyingObj = document.getElementById ("flying");
        flyingObj.style.left = mouseX + "px";
        flyingObj.style.top = mouseY + "px";
 }
    this.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null
  }


</script>
 </head>
 <body onmousemove="UpdateFlyingObj (event);" >
<h1><center>Homework 13.7<center></h1>
<div style="height:1000px;"></div>

<img id="flying" src="flying.gif" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key-point that needs to be considered is handling the ondragstart event of the image. Failing to return false from it means that the browser absorbs the event and gives odd behaviour. See comment in the source.

Try this on for size. (dont forget to change the image-path)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#flying 
{
    position: absolute; 
}
</style>

<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', myInitFunc, false);

function myInitFunc()
{
    byId('flying').addEventListener('mousedown', onImgMouseDown, false);
}

function onImgMouseDown(e)
{
    e = e || event;
    var mElem = this;
    var initMx = e.pageX;
    var initMy = e.pageY;
    var initElemX = this.offsetLeft;
    var initElemY = this.offsetTop;

    var dx = initMx - initElemX;
    var dy = initMy - initElemY;

    document.onmousemove = function(e)
    {
        e = e || event;
        mElem.style.left = e.pageX-dx+'px';
        mElem.style.top = e.pageY-dy+'px';
    }
    this.onmouseup = function()
    {
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }

    // try to comment-out the below line
    // doing so means the browser absorbs the ondragstart event and (in Chrome) drags a reduced-opacity copy of
    // the image, overlaid with a circle that has a diagonal line through it. - just like the usuall behaviour for
    // dragging an image on a webpage.
    this.ondragstart = function() { return false; }
}

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1><center>Homework 13.7<center></h1>
    <img id="flying" src="img/opera.svg"/>
</body>
</html>
```